# matplotlib plot points look fuzzy in Python, sharp in IPython

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython

I'm really confused here; the same code in Python and in IPython Notebook produces two different PNG files with `savefig`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5,4))
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
abc = np.random.uniform(size=(50000,3))
print abc.shape
x = (2*abc[:,0]-abc[:,1]-abc[:,2])/3.0
y = (abc[:,1]-abc[:,2])/np.sqrt(3)
ax.plot(x,y,'.',markersize=0.25)
ax.set_aspect('equal')
ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')
with open('/tmp/screenshots/foo.png','wb') as f:
    fig.savefig(f, format='png')
```

IPython Notebook:

[image]

Python:

[image]

It's the same PC with the same version of Python in both cases. Is there a way to get the image formatting in IPython using both methods? The Python version produces fuzzy dots and looks poor.

Answer (score 1):

Argh -- I figured it out, the `dpi` parameter gets chosen somehow differently in the two cases, and if I force it to `dpi=72` then it looks nice:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5,4))
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
abc = np.random.uniform(size=(50000,3))
print abc.shape
x = (2*abc[:,0]-abc[:,1]-abc[:,2])/3.0
y = (abc[:,1]-abc[:,2])/np.sqrt(3)
ax.plot(x,y,'.',markersize=0.25)
ax.set_aspect('equal')
ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')
with open('/tmp/screenshots/foo.png','wb') as f:
    fig.savefig(f, format='png', dpi=72)
```